# C# .net GridView.DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In .aspx I have

```
<body>
  <form id="form2" runat="server">
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Width="100%" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
 <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="id" HeaderText="iD" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="nme" HeaderText="Name" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
   </form>
</body>
```

In .cs I have

```
private void Grid()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, nme FROM mytable"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView.DataSource = dt; //error occurs here
                    GridView.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I receive the error 
CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'BaseDataBoundControl.DataSource'

The .cs does not seem to recognize the GridView from the .aspx page.
using .net 4.6.1

Comment: You forgot to put the data type in  'using (dt = new DataTable())'

Answer (score 5):

Don't call your GridView "GridView". The framework doesn't know whether you're talking about your instance of the GridView or whether you're talking about the class [GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx). That's confusing to discuss, and it's confusing for the compiler. Change the ID to something else that doesn't conflict with a pre-existing type name, and update your code behind appropriately. You usually name it after what it contains, ex `CustomersGridView`.

Markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="CustomersGridView" runat="server">
```

Code behind

```
CustomersGridView.DataSource = dt;
CustomersGridView.DataBind();
```